# Импорт модулей сразу для всех зависимостей

Tags: python, python-3.x, модули

Итак:

```
# test1.py
import timeit
from test2 import foo

print(timeit.default_timer())
t.foo()

# test2.py
def foo():
    print(timeit.default_timer())
```

При запуске получается, что в *test2.py* импортированного модуля нет. Как возможно обойти это и либо импортировать сразу для всей папки определенные модули, чтобы можно было использовать их сразу во всех файлах, либо импортировать "по цепочке"?

Comment: Так модуль который вы импортируете в test1.py не каким образом не может появится в test2.py, и в чем смысл данной конструкции ? зачем выносить в отдельный модуль функцию если вы все зависимости для нее собираетесь импортировать в главном файле ? это ломает всю суть модульной системы, ну и пишите тогда весь код в одном файле, а то что вы хотели добиться данным примером скорее всего называется "паттерн фасад", почитайте о нем, думаю именно он вам нужен исходя из вопроса.

Comment: У вас в этом коде вообще что-то непонятное происходит. Сначала вы импортируете foo как отдельную функцию. Потом вы пытаетесь её вызывать как метод какого-то объекта t. Нельзя просто так взять свободную функцию, и вызвать её в качестве метода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import timeit` две функции выполняет:

1. находит и инициализирует модуль
2. прикрепляет модуль к имени `timeit` в текущем пространстве имён. Работает как `timeit = <module>`.

Каждый модуль в Питоне образует отдельное пространство имён. Если вы напишите `var = 1` в одном модуле (`test1.py`), у вас не появится  магически `var` переменная в другом модуле (`test2.py`). Все имена, кроме встроенных таких как len, int, range, etc, необходимо явно вводить.

Если вы хотите использовать timeit в `test2.py` модуле, добавьте `import timeit` в `test2.py` модуле.

Какие имена может `test2.foo` функция использовать как правило статически определяется. timeit не появится в `test2.py` только потому что вы сделали `import timeit` в `test1.py`.

Технически можно `test2.var = 1` выполнить, чтобы var глобальная переменная появилась в модуле test2, но этого следует избегать, кроме особых случаев. Как правило это используется, чтобы уже существующие имена переопределить (monkey patching).